# Is the Raspberry Pi's Sense HAT compatible with other computers?

Tags: sense-hat

I'm trying to interface the sense HAT with a PIC24 based non-Raspberry Pi motherboard. I'm not good with computer hardware and standards so I don't know what other information to give for a useful answer. The purpose of this is to use the sensor package of the sense HAT for a balloon launch to gather telemetry data.

Comment: You will need to identify the interface between the Pi and the senseHat for each sensor.  Probably one or more of serial, SPI, I2C, GPIO.  You will then need to ensure that the PIC24 can implement each of those interfaces.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at "sensor boards" for the Arduino as it more closely resembles the PIC24. Here's a recent [press release from ROHM](https://www.electronicsweekly.com/news/business/rohm-offers-sebsor-expansion-board-arduino-2018-06/) announcing a board "designed for use with existing open platform MCU boards such as Arduino". Try Google search with `arduino sensor expansion board` to get "geographically correct" results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sense HAT has a couple of sensors, all of which are interfaced over I2C. The sensors are **LPS25H(pressure/temp sensor), LSM9DS1(IMU), HTS221(Humidity and temperature sensor) and LED2472G(Led Driver)**. More details on the pinout are [here](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/sense_hat).

The sense hat has a python library available [here](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-sense-hat/blob/master/sense_hat/sense_hat.py) and all the functionality other than for the LED array is implemented in another library called RTIMULib [here](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/RTIMULib).

Now, if you connect to the Sense hat from another MCU via I2C, all the sensors would be available on the I2C interface, however you will have to write libraries to get them working if the libraries are not already available for your MCU. Libraries for these sensors are available for Arduino, so you can port them to your platform. Here's the library for the IMU as an [example](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_LSM9DS1_Arduino_Library). If you have to port them and have not done it before for another sensor, it might be a little tricky to get it working.